# Apple Not turning on

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 6s has had its battery replaced 2 times now and the first time I got it replaced it worked but then shut down during the night and never turned back on even when trying the factory reset, the second time I got it replaced it was working and again it shut down during the night and is not turning back on I have tried everything including the factory reset nothing is working

Comment: Does the company that replaced the battery offer a warranty on the device or the service?

Comment: the service yes but the device no I have a feeling it has nothing to do with the battery as it worked fine all day until I leave it next to my bed side table with 100% of charge and then it just won't turn back on in the morning